# After visiting Jordan, would I be interrogated back in the UK?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, uk-citizens, jordan, amman

Does anyone have a history of being interrogated on entry into the UK due to travel to Amman, Jordan?

I have an upcoming business trip there and considering if wise to travel there on my UK passport.

Trying to avoid any unnecessary issues on getting a Jordanian stamp on my passport.

Comment: If you're a UK citizen, then they aren't allowed to prevent you reentering. You can also assume that unless you go to some length to hide it,the  UK government knows you have been there. I'm curious as to why you think visiting Jordan would be a problem? Do you actually have any other passports you could use?

Comment: Jordan is (still) a well-known tourism destination and I have never seen it on lists of “sensitive” countries of any kind.

Answer (score 7):

The current [Foreign Office](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/jordan) travel advice for Jordan warns against travel close to the Syrian border, for obvious reasons. Travel to other areas of Jordan is fine. You should familiarise yourself with the information they provide about safety etc. although most of it is common sense.

It also says that over sixty thousand British nationals visited Jordan in 2015, so it is not such a rare occurrence that they would scrutinise someone just for having been there.

As a UK citizen, you may not even need to interact with immigration officials at all. If you have an e-passport and are travelling to an airport/terminal that has them you can use the e-passport gates, and avoid human interaction pretty much entirely.

Comment: If there are many people for the e-passport booths and not many for the human officers, you may be send on to see a human, so be smart about your position in the lines.

Comment: thanks guys..my biometric chip doesn't work so i always get passed to the officers..